# Why is event beforeRemove mentioned in the template binding docs when it doesn't do anything?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've been reading the [knockoutjs docs about the template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html). Specifically, I'd like to be able to hook the moment the template was rendered, and again, the moment just prior to the rendered template being removed (by, for instance, changing the name property of the binding). The docs ***seem*** to maybe suggest that the afterRender and beforeRemove event are what I'm interested in.

So I have the following markup:

```
<script type="text/html" id="templ1">
    foo!
</script>
<script type="text/html" id="templ2">
    bar!
</script>
<!-- ko if: templateName()&&templateName().length>0 -->
<div data-bind="template:{name:templateName(),afterRender:ar,beforeRemove:br}">
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

and the following javascript

```
$(function(){
    var vm={
        templateName:ko.observable("templ1"),
        ar:function(){
            alert("afterRender");
        },
        br:function(){
            alert("beforeRemove");
        }
    };
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    setTimeout(function(){
        vm.templateName("templ2");
    },5000);
});
```

The afterRender event is firing off fine. The beforeRemove event doesn't fire.

What's up here? Have I just misunderstood the docs?

Have a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/a3xG2/3/).

Comment: I got beforeRemove - like behaviour via a different method: http://jsfiddle.net/a3xG2/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-4-using-afterrender-afteradd-and-beforeremove , the `beforeRemove` event is part of the `foreach` binding and happens before a DOM node is removed because of an element removal on an array.

> beforeRemove — is invoked when an array item has been removed, but before the corresponding DOM nodes have been removed. If you specify a beforeRemove callback, then it becomes your responsibility to remove the DOM nodes.

Comment: Seems completely pointless mentioning this on the documents for the template binding when they don't have any relevance to a template.

Answer (score 1):

`beforeRemove` is meant to be used only with the foreach binding